# Android emulator & webcam

Tags: camera, android-emulator, simulation, barcode-scanner

I am currently trying to test my application on an emulator (Android 7.0) from the Android Studio. It requires access to the camera to be able to read barcodes. I have tried using a webcam but it is almost impossible to pick up the level of detail I need for the barcode to be properly detected.

Can anyone recommend a way that I can simulator what the emulated camera on the emulator is displaying? E.g. set the camera input as a image file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emulate the camera on the emulator to use the webcam on your computer. To do that, edit the emulator, go to the advanced setting. Under "Camera" Front/Back select "webcam". Now when you turn on camera on emulator, it will use your computers webcam.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you achieve that. https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator#add_augmented_images_to_the_scene

Sample image from my emulator:
[image]